# How can I extract all matches from Col A that meet a criteria in Col B in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to pull all the invoice numbers (Col A) that list "509" in Dept (Col B) so that I can see all the SKUs tied to these invoice numbers.

My data set looks like:

```
Invoice Number  Dept    Class   Sku Year    Month

00919543SK  136 63  36667281    F 2017  F 2017/12      
00919544SK  115 11  23900564    F 2017  F 2017/12      
00919545SK  117 93  33636431    F 2017  F 2017/12      
00919545SK  117 21  25160533    F 2017  F 2017/12      
00919545SK  509 10  50910       F 2017  F 2017/12      
00919546SK  136 23  32269311    F 2017  F 2017/12      
00919547SK  115 41  22309307    F 2017  F 2017/12
```

Filtering by "509" doesn't work since I can't see all the different SKUs tied to an Invoice # with Dept 509. I've also tried a number of INDEX and MATCH formulas but couldn't find an efficient method that didn't require me to pull down the formula to the nth row. I haven't worked with macros before but would like to start learning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What would be an example of the desired results given the data in the question?

Comment: The entire dataset is much bigger but given the provided dataset, the desired result would be the invoice # in one column (in this case, 00919545SK) and then all the SKU #s tied to that invoice # in a different column (in this case, 33636431, 25160533, 50910). In essence, I'm trying to create a filtered data set with only Invoice #s that had Dept 509 and their associated SKUs.

Answer (score 0):

A `COUNTIFS` function will do what I think you're looking for here:

In a new column, type `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,509)`

That should give you an answer greater than 0 for every row of an invoice if any of the invoice's rows have the 509 dept.

Comment: I put your dataset in columns starting with col A, and it gave me the expected result. So, for my formula, col A is invoice number, and col B is Dept. If that matches your sheet, maybe check to see if the 509 isn't a text value. If it is, put the 509 in quotes, and it should find it.